# How to refresh a DIV with random different names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I´m doing like this. Works fine with just one div with a static name.

Problem is when i want to refresh **DIV´s with other names like myDiv1, myDiv2 etc.**

I have tried javascript by sending ID to the funciton, my webpage jumps up to the begining, I dont want that to happen. That doesn't happen with the code below.

```
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
     $("#myDiv").load("update.php")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})


<div id = 'myDiv" . $row["id"]. "' ><a href='#' id='refresh'> Click Here </a></div>
```

---

This Would also work, but then I have to generate one jquery-function for every DIV

```
$(function() {
  $("#refresh1").click(function(evt) {
     $("#myDiv1").load("update.php")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})


<div id = "myDiv1" ><a href='#' id='refresh1'> Click Here 1 </a></div>



$(function() {
  $("#refresh2").click(function(evt) {
     $("#myDiv2").load("update.php")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})


<div id = "myDiv2" ><a href='#' id='refresh2'> Click Here 2 </a></div>
```

Comment: What does *"jumps up to the begining"* mean? Does it scroll to the top, or does it redirect somewhere ?

Comment: The page refresh and starts at the begining. Like when you press F5. Tje jquery update my div and stays at the position (no scroll)

Comment: Can you post the HTML? So one refresh button, reloads all divs? Or each div has it's own button?

Comment: I just whant to refresh one DIV.

Comment: $(function() {
  $("#refresh[ID]").click(function(evt) {
     $("#myDiv").load("update.php")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})
<div id = 'myDiv" . $row["id"]. "' <a href='#' id='refresh[ID]'> Click Here </a> ---------->Something like this

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what you want to achieve. By the looks of it you will have multiple div's each with it's own refresh button. And you want to update the div that with the same ID as the refresh button.

Comment: Yes, each did has its own button or href-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent element in the click event and execute the load on it like this:

```
$(this).parent().load("update.php");
```

If you don't want a redirection to happen, I would suggest that you don't use a link. Maybe a button or a span

Comment: Great. Mark the answer as accepted and an upvote would be nice too

Answer (score 0):

You may selects elements by beginning part of your id:

`$('div[id ^= "myDiv"]')`

Comment: How do i send the ID to the function?

Comment: function test(id){
 $("#mydiv" + id).load("update.php"); works with js